# Is Rails find deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is Rails `find` method deprecated?

In the olden days, `find(1)` was the preferred way to find by id.

Is it better to use `find_by(id:1)` instead of `find(1)`?

Comment: `find` is the very first method mentioned in the ActiveRecord [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object), so I think it's safe to say it's still the way to go.

Comment: Do you see deprecated in RubyMine? If yes, it is know and reported bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17979

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither method is deprecated (as far as I know). The difference between `find` and `find_by()` is what they return when a record does not exist. If a record with an ID of 23 does not exist, this is what you get:

```
Model.find(23)
=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Model with 'id'=23
```

Or

```
Model.find_by(id: 23)
=> nil
```

Using `find_by` is more forgiving if you're making queries where a non-existent record is possible because you get a `nil` value rather than an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are referring to the deprecation of [ActiveRecord::Base#find](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) like **find(:first)** and **find(:all)** that are deprecated in favor of first and all methods.

Support for this methods has been removed from **rails 3.2**.

The method you've used ([ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find)) is not deprecated .

Comment: FWIW, I think the confusion is with the `find_by_xxx` methods. I think those were deprecated in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 4.2.1, it is not. [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find) is the API documentation for it (not official, but pretty good). What I think you were looking at is [this method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class), which was deprecated in Rails 3.0.0.

I've never used the method `find_by()`. I believe the better/newer method to use is the `where()` method, like so:

```
User.where(name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
```

Comment: `where` is not better/newer, it just does something different. And that deprecated find you link to is still basically the same method. It's just moved from `Base` to `FinderMethods`.

Comment: `find_by(x)` can be thought of as an equivalent to `where(x).first`.

Comment: .where() returns an array of objects whereas .find_by() returns an instance of an object.